# Solving DE without using integral?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The question is :

$\text{Find every fucntion $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $f^{'}(x) = 2 \sqrt{f(x)}$}$.

Without using integral, is there anyway to solve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Put $f(x) = (u(x))^2$

Comment: You may use the approach *God told me $f(x)=(x+a)^2$ is a solution*. Then prove they are the only solutions.

Comment: But there's also the trivial solution.

Comment: Instead of going with @JackD'Aurizio 's approach, you could assume $f$ is a polynomial, and go from there.

Comment: One should recognize this equation as the standard counter-example to the uniqueness theorem. It has also the solutions $\max(0, x-c)^2$ which for any $c\in [0,1]$ gives a solution that satisfies the restrictions in the task.